# Parsing Compound type XML

Tags: xml, soap, xml-parsing

I have a SOAP web service that returns an XML in this format

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:GetResponse>
      <ret SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns2:Map[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
         <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
           <item>
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">ProtocolId</key>
              <value xsi:type="xsd:string">1</value>
           </item>
           <item>
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Title</key>
              <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Some Title</value>
           </item>
           <item>
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Text</key>
              <value xsi:type="xsd:string"> Some Text </value>
           </item>
         </item> 
         <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
           <item>
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">ProtocolId</key>
              <value xsi:type="xsd:string">2</value>
           </item>
           <item>
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Title</key>
              <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Another Title</value>
           </item>
           <item>
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Text</key>
              <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Another Text </value>
           </item>
         </item> 
      </ret>
   </ns1:GetResponse>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

How to write a parser for this kind of XML. If you have some examples, it will be of great help.

Thanks

Mukul

Comment: What do you mean by "write a parser"? Aren't there enough XML parsers available already?

Comment: Sorry for wording wrongly, my problem is that this particular XML is very large, and the android device runs out of memory while trying to parse it, since its heap is very small (16 MB). So, i wanted some customised parser where i could write the contents of this XML into a db file directly, instead of creating a list of 1500+ objects.

Comment: @Mukul: There is a [SAX parser available for Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html). This should be pretty memory efficient, since SAX does not build a DOM. Have you tried this approach already? *(Tip: Use @ replies to notify people if you answer them, or they might miss your response)*

Comment: @Tomalak: Thank you for the information, i am trying the SAX parser for android now.

Comment: @Mukul: If you manage to make it work, it would be great if you posted your solution below (outline description, small code sample). It'd certainly be better and more useful than other answers since you know the problem best. I'd come back and vote it up if you do.

Comment: @Tomalak: Hi, I have written the parser and have pasted it here for future reference. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work with this parser -

```
public class XmlPullFeedParser extends BaseFeedParser {
public XmlPullFeedParser(String feedUrl) {
    super(feedUrl);
}

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int whichItemFlag = 0;

Context thisContext;

DataBaseHelper myDB;

public void parse(InputStream is, Context context, String insertInto) {

    XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();

    thisContext = context;
    myDB = new DataBaseHelper(thisContext);
    try {
        // auto-detect the encoding from the stream
        parser.setInput(is, "UTF-8");
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        boolean done = false;
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && !done) {
            String name = null;
            String attr = null;
            switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                attr = parser.getAttributeName(0);
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM)) {
                    if(attr!=null) {
                        builder.append("(");
                    }
                    whichItemFlag++;
                } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(VALUE)) {
                    builder.append("'"+parser.nextText().replaceAll("'", "&#39;")+"',");
                } 
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM)) {
                    whichItemFlag--;
                    if(whichItemFlag==0) {
                        builder.delete(builder.length()-1, builder.length());
                        builder.append(")");
                        writeStringToDb(insertInto, builder.toString());
                        builder.delete(0, builder.length());
                    }
                } 
                break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
//          throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        myDB.close();
    }
}

private void writeStringToDb(String insertInto, String string) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDB.getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = insertInto + string;
    db.execSQL(sql);
    db.close();
}
```

The Stringbuilder i have used to create a string out of the values returned by the XML and use this string directly to write to the database. The parse method takes an inputstream, the application context and a string that helps me build the sql statement. From the parser itself i write directly to the database. Since the XML was very large (7MB), i had to do it this way otherwise my android device would run out of memory while building 1500+ objects.